# How to disable vmware workstation taskbar preview?

Tags: vmware-workstation

VMWare workstation uses the new taskbar preview feature in windows 7 - click on the icon in the taskbar and instead of switching to the app it shows you the open tabs. I just want to switch to the app. Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

I've tried to check the vmware website, but it's pretty awful.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it's at the top of the results of Google searches on the topic. The accepted answer seems to be wrong, could you change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/264637;jsessionid=9A13ED63777BF6923DCCA2DE8231BAE4?tstart=15), you cannot turn this "feature" off in VMWare Workstation 7.  I, too, find it to be annoying.  I just want one single VMWare entry on my taskbar, but instead I get a taskbar item for every open VM, plus the "Home" tab.  When I want to switch to VMWare Workstation, clicking on the entry on the taskbar isn't enough.  Instead, I have to click on the group of eight VMWare buttons and choose one from the previews that pop up.  It's a step backwards in usability compared to VMWare Workstation 6.5, but unfortunately it's what we're stuck with for now.

Answer (score 15):

Edit -> Preferences

On the Workspace (default) section, unselect "Show Aero Peek thumbnails for open tabs"

Answer (score 1):

Hold Ctrl while clicking the button.

Answer (score -1):

I have looked for the same issue, and I did not find any way to disable the preview's. My solution is to close all of the open tabs of the VM's (by default they are all opened), and leave just the VM's that are currently in your use (you can leave VM's to working in the background). That way, you see in the Taskbar only the VM's that you're heavily working on (which can be just one, in you case).